# UnparsedFlagAccessError: Trying to access flag --preserve_unused_tokens before flags were parsed. BERT

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I want to use Bert language model for training a multi class text classification task.
Previously I trained using LSTM without any Error but Bert gives me this Error.
I get the following Error and I really don't know how to solve it, can anyone help me please?

Unfortunately there is very little documentation using BERT in keras library.

```
!wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/official/nlp/bert/tokenization.py

import tensorflow_hub as hub
from bert import tokenization
module_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2'
bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer(module_url, trainable=True)





vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy()
do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case)

def bert_encode(texts, tokenizer, max_len=512):
    all_tokens = []
    all_masks = []
    all_segments = []
    
    for text in texts:
        text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
            
        text = text[:max_len-2]
        input_sequence = ["[CLS]"] + text + ["[SEP]"]
        pad_len = max_len - len(input_sequence)
        
        tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(input_sequence) + [0] * pad_len
        pad_masks = [1] * len(input_sequence) + [0] * pad_len
        segment_ids = [0] * max_len
        
        all_tokens.append(tokens)
        all_masks.append(pad_masks)
        all_segments.append(segment_ids)
    
    return np.array(all_tokens), np.array(all_masks), np.array(all_segments)



def build_model(bert_layer, max_len=512):
    input_word_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    input_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_mask")
    segment_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="segment_ids")

    pooled_output, sequence_output = bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])
    clf_output = sequence_output[:, 0, :]
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='softmax')(clf_output)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='softmax')(net)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(net)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(net)
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids], outputs=out)
    model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model



max_len = 150
train_input = bert_encode(data.text_cleaned, tokenizer, max_len=max_len)
```

Error as following :

```
UnparsedFlagAccessError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-fd64df42591d> in <module>()
      1 import sys
      2 max_len = 150
----> 3 train_input = bert_encode(o.text_cleaned, tokenizer, max_len=max_len)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    496         # get too much noise.
    497         logging.error(error_message)
--> 498       raise _exceptions.UnparsedFlagAccessError(error_message)
    499 
    500   def __setattr__(self, name, value):

UnparsedFlagAccessError: Trying to access flag --preserve_unused_tokens before flags were parsed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/1133) you have to downgrade bert-tensorflow to 1.0.1. Check [this answer](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/1133#issuecomment-703818257) to find a solution. If you are following [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/simple-text-multi-classification-task-using-keras-bert/) downgrade bert-tensorflow and use the `!wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/official/nlp/bert/tokenization.py` as suggested because inside the python code the author has made the change from `tf.gfile.GFile(vocab_file, "r")` to `tf.io.gfile.Gfile(vocab_file, "r")`. After that code compiles successfully. Ping me if you want anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downgrading, you can set FLAGS in your code and you can use latest version of Bert.

```
import sys
from absl import flags
sys.argv=['preserve_unused_tokens=False']
flags.FLAGS(sys.argv)
```

Good luck!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I'm pretty new to this- are there any downsides to this solution?